# bootstrap 4 header not completely responsive

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to develop a completely responsive Bootstrap 4 fixed header. It does not work for all sizes - it wraps around.

The test site can be found here:
[Home Page](http://mtlfoundation.com/test/index.html)

```css
#header .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

#header .navbar {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#header .navbar a {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#header .navbar li {
  padding-right: 18px;
}

#header .navbar-brand {
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <section id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mtlNavbar">
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>              
                    </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mtlNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
              <li class="lead_1"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
              <li class="lead_1"><a href="#center">ABOUT</a></li>
              <li class="lead_1"><a href="#gallery">HOW WE HELP</a></li>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/mtlLogo-blackBackground.png" width=150px></a>
              <li class="lead_1"><a href="#benefits">BENEFITS OF SPORTS</a></li>
              <li class="lead_1"><a href="#donate">DONATE</a></li>
              <li class="lead_1"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the header is wrapping? It especially happens when testing iPads, but I suspect there are other widths it does not work for. Thanks

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to provide your HTML.

Comment: Please include a [mre], in the question itself. See [ask], and the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552)

Comment: An anchor element is an invalid child of a list. You'll want to fix that before continuing. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: sorry about that.  Somehow the html was not showing. I edited the original question.

Comment: See if you can fix the demo snippet to show the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ktpmm5/sxnja6L7/24/

The menu should be vertical and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Instead of

```css
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

I used:

```css
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to create a menu with a centered logo and display the first three menu items to the left of the logo and the remaining three to the right.

Placing the logo as one of the menu elements is not a good idea, considering what Bootstrap does under the hood and all the implications on mobile devices. It might work, but is not ideal.

In my estimation, the cleanest way to do it is to create a separate menu having only the first three items and hide it on mobile. The "normal" menu will also hide its first three items at all times, except on mobile.

Here's an example:

```css
#first-container,
#navbarNav {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#first-container {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  #navbarNav {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-brand img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -.5rem;
  }
  .navbar-nav:not(#_) {
    padding-left: 11rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
  <ul id="first-container" class="navbar-nav d-none d-lg-flex flex-row ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        One
        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Three</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jurhp.jpg"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse mr-auto">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item d-block d-lg-none">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
          One
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-block d-lg-none">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-block d-lg-none">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Three</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Four</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Five</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Six</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In my example, `#navbarNav` is the `id` of the "normal" navbar (as I've taken it directly from their examples). `#first-container` is the one I added. I tried to keep the overrides to an absolute minimum.

Important note: in what you have, the logo is not centered. The menu is centered, as a whole, but your logo is off from page center (you'll notice when scrolling). In what I made above, the logo be always centered, and left/right menus can have variable sizes, they don't push the logo around.